# Как запретить ввод определенных символов в текстовый виджет Text() tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хотелось бы узнать, как запретить в реальном времени ввод определенных символов? К примеру букв, чтобы при нажатии на соответствующие символам клавиши, ничего не выводилось в виджет, как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Python')
root.geometry('158x55')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    
First_line = Frame(root, background='olivedrab')    

Expression = Text(First_line, background = "silver", foreground = "black",
                  width = 17, height=3)

Expression.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2) 

First_line.pack(anchor = W)  


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно привязаться к событию нажатия клавиши, и если введена буква, то вернуть строку "break" из обработчика, тогда событие не будет отправлено следующим обработчикам, в том числе и стандартному, который отвечает за вывод букв в текстовое поле.

```
def check_keys(event):
    if event.char.isalpha():
        return "break"


Expression.bind("<Key>", check_keys)
```

Но это не защитит от вставки текста с буквами из буфера обмена.

Можно запретить возможность вставки через Ctrl-V, для этого нужно дополнить условие:

```
def check_keys(event: Event):
    # Условие event.state & 4 проверяет, что зажат Ctrl
    if event.char.isalpha() or (event.state & 4 and event.keysym == "v"):
        return "break"
```

---

Для текстовых полей `Entry` (не `Text`) также можно применять валидацию:

```
Expression = Entry(First_line, background = "silver", foreground = "black")

Expression.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2) 


def check_keys(text, action):
    # Не событие вставки или ни один символ в тексте не является буквой
    return action != '1' or not any(char.isalpha() for char in text)


Expression.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(Expression.register(check_keys),'%P','%d'))
```

На основе примера с английского stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554720/4752653 [@user1683793](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683793)

Такой вариант защищает от вставки текста с буквами из буфера обмена, но для `Text` такой вариант не работает, выкидывает ошибку `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-validate"`

Comment: Причина почему я использовал Text() в том, что в нем создается окно с несколькими строками, для меня это выглядит предпочтительно, отсюда возникает вопрос, возможно ли как то в методе Entry() реализовать несколько строк?

Comment: Нет, Entry это однострочное текстовое поле.